# Stop jQuery UI Toggle Animation

Tags: jquery-ui, toggle

I'm animating elements on the page and stop the animations when the browser is resizing.

All elements animated by animate() are stopped, but not the one with toggle() with jQueryUI effect.

Below is the function.

```
function animateMainEyelid()
{
    $main_eyelid.delay(1000).toggle('blind', {direction: 'up'}, 3000);
}

function stopMainEyeLid()
{
    $main_eyelid.stop(true, true);
}
```

Can anyone help me if there is anyway to stop the animation triggered inside the toggle function,or the other way to execute the animation that can be stopped?

Comment: do you want that the toggling `div` doesn't toggle if something happens?

Comment: Can you post HTML please?

Comment: I made a jsfiddle sample. When you click 'stop' while it's animating, it doesn't stop the animation. It finishes the current animation no matter what. http://jsfiddle.net/jessiebang7/p43rW/21/

Comment: I just found the solution and updated the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jessiebang7/p43rW/28/